# List(Of <custom class>) Seems to Reset Itself

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

### Code:

I have a class, `Pricing.vb`, that accepts an `IEnumerable(Of tblAccount)` in its new method, where `tblAccount` is an Entity Framework class with an added partial class that adds non-mapped properties.

Pricing.vb:

```
Public Property accounts As IEnumerable(Of tblAccount)

Public Sub New(ByVal accts As IEnumerable(Of tblAccount))
    Me.accounts = accts
End Sub
```

tblAccount.vb:

```
Partial Public Class tblAccount
    <NotMapped>
    Public Property irr As Double
End Class
```

The `Pricing.vb` class then has a method, `CalcBalance`:

```
Public Sub CalcBalance(reqPrice As Double)
    Dim acctsByIRR As List(Of Long)
    Dim i As Long = 0

    Me.FillCashFlows(reqPrice)
    Me.FillMetrics()
    acctsByIRR = Me.accounts.OrderBy(Function(t) t.irr).Select(Function(t) t.acct_id).ToList()

    'do ... while that removes accounts 1 by 1 by lowest ray until it is above min
    Do While Me.netIRR < Me.minimumIRR
        Me.accounts = Me.accounts.Where(Function(t) t.acct_id <> acctsByIRR(i))
        i = i + 1
        If Me.accounts.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Me.FillCashFlows(reqPrice)
        Me.FillMetrics()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Basically, the `CalcBalance()` method is designed to remove `tblAccount` objects one-by-one from its property `Me.Accounts`, in order of lowest IRR, until the IRR of the remaining accounts (`Me.netIRR`) meets a minimum criteria (`Me.minimumIRR`).  The `Me.netIRR` property is calculated by methods `FillCashFlows()` and `FillMetrics()`.

### Problem:

The problem that I'm seeing, though, is that `Me.accounts` essentially resets itself each time the do while...loop loops.  So if I have `tblAccounts` with `acct_id`s 1 through 5, and let's say that the order of lowest IRRs is 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, then the first time the method loops it will properly remove `acct_id=1` from `Me.accounts`.  BUT, the next time it loops, `acct_id=1` will reappear in `Me.accounts`, and it will remove `acct_id=2`.  It will continue this weird process until of course it hits an index out of range exception.

### For a little visualization, here's what the `IEnumerable(Of tblAccount)` looks like, by `acct_id` after each loop:

After 1st loop:

```
2
3
4
5
```

After 2nd loop:

```
1
3
4
5
```

After 3rd loop:

```
1
2
4
5
```

After 4th loop:

```
1
2
3
5
```

After 5th loop:

```
1
2
3
4
```

### It should look like this:

After 1st loop:

```
2
3
4
5
```

After 2nd loop:

```
3
4
5
```

After 3rd loop:

```
4
5
```

After 4th loop:

```
5
```

After 5th loop:

```
empty, and Exit Sub
```

Comment: What does `Me.FillCashFlows(reqPrice)` and `Me.FillMetrics()` do? Is that repopulating the items?

Comment: They fill other class properties with cash flows for each account, then calculate metrics like yield/irr per account and for the whole of accounts.  They do not repopulate `Me.accounts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `IEnumerable<T>` and not `List<T>`. LINQ query is lazy loaded, so your `accounts` property stores the query information (*how* to get the results) not a list of accounts. In every iteration of `Do/While` you just change the definition, and later on it's called against initial data source over and over again.

Make sure to call `ToList` whenever you assign to `accounts`:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal accts As IEnumerable(Of tblAccount))
    Me.accounts = accts.ToList()
End Sub
```

and

```
Public Sub CalcBalance(reqPrice As Double)
    Dim acctsByIRR As List(Of Long)
    Dim i As Long = 0

    Me.FillCashFlows(reqPrice)
    Me.FillMetrics()
    acctsByIRR = Me.accounts.OrderBy(Function(t) t.irr).Select(Function(t) t.acct_id).ToList()

    'do ... while that removes accounts 1 by 1 by lowest ray until it is above min
    Do While Me.netIRR < Me.minimumIRR
        Me.accounts = Me.accounts.Where(Function(t) t.acct_id <> acctsByIRR(i)).ToList()
        i = i + 1
        If Me.accounts.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Me.FillCashFlows(reqPrice)
        Me.FillMetrics()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: My god... 2 hours of banging my head against a wall, and the answer is right there.  I actually started converting everything to a List, but then stopped for some reason.  Thank you so much.